# Applying operation to unique groups of ids in a table in SAS?

Tags: sql, group-by, sas

I have a table of values for example below. I would like to get the most recent rows of each loan id. I can get the most recent values by using the (OBS=2) function, but can't group the data to apply each operation.

I've searched online and can't do do loops in proc sql. I also can't use groupby because that just gives me summary statistics. If anyone could recommend a method to try, and even shwo me some pseudocode of how to approach the problem would be great.

```
loan_id Date    princ_amt   del_status
1      1012016  70           0
1      2012016  60           7
1      3012016  50           9
1      4012016  40           9
1      5012016  30           7
1      6012016  20           7
1      7012016  10           1
1      8012016  0            0
1      9012016  0            0
1      10012016 0            0
1      11012016 0            0
1      12012016 0            0
2      1012016  70           0
2      2012016  60           0
2      3012016  50           0
2      4012016  40           1
2      5012016  30           7
2      6012016  20           7
2      7012016  10           8
2      8012016  0            0
2      9012016  0            0
2      10012016 0            0
2      11012016 0            0
2      12012016 0            0
```

Comment: which db you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is SAS, use a Data Step with a `by` group.

```
data want;
set have;
by loan_id;
retain cnt 0;
if first.loan_id then
   cnt = 0;

cnt = cnt + 1;

if cnt <=2 then output;

drop cnt;
run;
```

We loop through the data and count the number of observation by `loan_id`.  Use `retain` to keep the value of `cnt` between observations.  If the count is less than or equal to 2 then we output the record.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply want the LAST row for each *loan_id* when you sort by *date* in ascending order.

```
PROC SORT DATA=dset1; BY loan_id date; RUN;

DATA dset2;
  SET dset1;
  BY loan_id;
  IF LAST.loan_id;
RUN;
```

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to extend this from the most recent month to the most recent 6 months?

Comment: That would mean mutliple rows per loan_id?  If so, take "dset2" and do a JOIN with "dset1" ON a.loan_id=b.loan_id WHERE  0 LE a.date-b.date LE 180.